# IBAction button stays active

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ibaction, iboutlet

I have 2 buttons each below each other and depending on a function it shows what button is enabled and what button is disabled.

```
@IBOutlet weak var startBtn: workoutButton!
@IBOutlet weak var restBtn: workoutButton!

@IBAction func startBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        startBtn.isHidden = true
        startBtn.isEnabled = false
        perform(#selector(workoutStartVC.revealRestModeBtn), with: 1, afterDelay: 10)
        timeLeft = 0
        myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(workoutStartVC.timerRunning), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @IBAction func restBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        print("rest mode button is pressed and i am showing a overlay right now with data count down")
    }
```

When a click the restBtn it still executes the code in the startBtnPressed. How is this possible? Because when I click startBtnPressed 1 time it should disable the button and hide it. It hides it but I am still able to execute the function. So the timer goes twice as fast.

Thanks for the help!

Kevin.

Comment: So when you hit the `restBtn` it executes `startBtnPressed`? If that is the case, you probably just have your IB connections setup badly. If you go into your storyboard/xib and right click on the button you can see what actions it is activating.

Comment: sometimes I am feeling stupid...

Answer (score 1):

Open your storyboard, select resetButton and make sure there is only one action attached in "Sent Events" section. Right now you will see both IBActions attached to it.

It should be like this:

[image]

You probably have something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete the IBAction Connection and reconnect them.

This problem happens when both buttons are hooked to both methods.

This usually happens, if you have copied and pasted a button the storyboard.